# Getting error "Invalid operation" for VERSA SDWAN router in Ansible Automation

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-awx, bastion-host

I am facing issue while connecting to VERSA FLEXVNF router via SSH through Bastion host with LDAP user where are everything working file with local user.

The main difference in the manual ssh login is that when I login with local user I get in to the linux shell whereas when I login with LDAP user is directly going to router CLI.

Note: LDAP user has all sudo rights

Local user uses default shell /bin/bash
Ldap user uses default shell as /opt/versa/scripts/aaa_scripts/vshell

`
bash-4.4# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.18
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/var/lib/awx/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 24 2020, 17:57:11) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]

`

```
**Login with Local user:**

[jumphostuser@JUMPHOST ~]$ ssh admin@TargetRouter
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*  Company assets, including this system, should be used only for        *
*      Company communications management approved purposes.              *
*                                                                     *
*  You should be aware that it may be a criminal offence to secure    *
*    unauthorised access to any program or data in the system or      *
*      to make any unauthorised modification to its contents.         *
*                                                                     *
*  If you are not authorised by Company management to access this        *
*                     system, please LOGOFF now.                      *
*                                                                     *
* Company internal systems business authorised management audit any time *
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

admin@TargetRouter's password:
             .---.,
            (      ``.
       _     \        )    __      ________ _____   _____
      (  `.   \      /     \ \    / /  ____|  __ \ / ____|  /\
       \    `. )    /       \ \  / /| |__  | |__) | (___   /  \
        \     |    /         \ \/ / |  __| |  _  / \___ \ / /\ \
         \    |   /           \  /  | |____| | \ \ ____) / ____ \
          \   |  /             \/   |______|_|  \_\_____/_/    \_\
           \  | /
            \_|/                     ___ _    _____  ___   ___  _ ___
                                    | __| |  | __\ \/ | \ / / \| | __|
                                    | _|| |__| _| >  < \ V /| .` | _|
                                    |_| |____|___/_/\_\ \_/ |_|\_|_|


Versa FlexVNF software
Release     :   21.2.3 (GA)
Release date:   20230909
Package ID  :   9397b39

Last login: Fri Mar 15 13:52:14 2024 from XX.XX.XX.XX
[admin@TargetRouter: ~] $
[admin@TargetRouter: ~] $
[admin@TargetRouter: ~] $


**Login with LDAP user:**

[jumphostuser@JUMPHOST ~]$ ssh jumphostuser@TargetIP
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*  Company assets, including this system, should be used only for        *
*      Company communications management approved purposes.              *
*                                                                     *
*  You should be aware that it may be a criminal offence to secure    *
*    unauthorised access to any program or data in the system or      *
*      to make any unauthorised modification to its contents.         *
*                                                                     *
*  If you are not authorised by Company management to access this        *
*                     system, please LOGOFF now.                      *
*                                                                     *
* Company internal systems business authorised management audit any time *
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

jumphostuser@TargetIP's password:
             .---.,
            (      ``.
       _     \        )    __      ________ _____   _____
      (  `.   \      /     \ \    / /  ____|  __ \ / ____|  /\
       \    `. )    /       \ \  / /| |__  | |__) | (___   /  \
        \     |    /         \ \/ / |  __| |  _  / \___ \ / /\ \
         \    |   /           \  /  | |____| | \ \ ____) / ____ \
          \   |  /             \/   |______|_|  \_\_____/_/    \_\
           \  | /
            \_|/                     ___ _    _____  ___   ___  _ ___
                                    | __| |  | __\ \/ | \ / / \| | __|
                                    | _|| |__| _| >  < \ V /| .` | _|
                                    |_| |____|___/_/\_\ \_/ |_|\_|_|


Versa FlexVNF software
Release     :   21.2.3 (GA)
Release date:   20230909
Package ID  :   9397b39

Last login: Mon Mar 18 13:13:13 2024 from XX.XX.XX.XX


             .---.,
            (      ``.
       _     \        )    __      ________ _____   _____
      (  `.   \      /     \ \    / /  ____|  __ \ / ____|  /\
       \    `. )    /       \ \  / /| |__  | |__) | (___   /  \
        \     |    /         \ \/ / |  __| |  _  / \___ \ / /\ \
         \    |   /           \  /  | |____| | \ \ ____) / ____ \
          \   |  /             \/   |______|_|  \_\_____/_/    \_\
           \  | /
            \_|/                   _  _ ___ _______      _____  ___ _  _____
                                  | \| | __|_   _\ \    / / _ \| _ \ |/ / __|
                                  | .` | _|  | |  \ \/\/ / (_) |   / ' <\__ \
                                  |_|\_|___| |_|   \_/\_/ \___/|_|_\_|\_\___/



jumphostuser connected from XX.XX.XX.XX using ssh on TargetRouter
jumphostuser@TargetRouter-cli>

=====================================

***** As I am directly going into CLI with LDAP user so trying send raw command "show system uptime". Below is my yaml

===========================
---
  - name: ssh connection test
    hosts: all
    become: false
    gather_facts: no
    tasks:
    - name: Get current Spack version
      raw: 'show system uptime'
============================

As I am using Ansible AWX tower I am passing environmental variables for bastion host as follows:

ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q jumphostuser@jumphostIP"'
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: '/var/lib/awx/projects/POC_SDWAN/PRIVATEKEY/id_rsa'

============================

**Below is debug log**

"stderr_lines": [
        "OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020",
        "debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config",
        "debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0",
        "debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf",
        "debug2: checking match for 'final all' host TargetRouter_IP originally TargetRouter_IP",
        "debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'",
        "debug2: match not found",
        "debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)",
        "debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config",
        "debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]",
        "debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]",
        "debug1: configuration requests final Match pass",
        "debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname TargetRouter_IP is address",
        "debug1: re-parsing configuration",
        "debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config",
        "debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0",
        "debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf",
        "debug2: checking match for 'final all' host TargetRouter_IP originally TargetRouter_IP",
        "debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'",
        "debug2: match found",
        "debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1",
        "debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config",
        "debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]",
        "debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]",
        "debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master",
        "debug1: Control socket \\"/tmp/bwrap_959_knd39plq/awx_959_a5darf8j/cp/e2d81b8595\\" does not exist",
        "debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W TargetRouter_IP:22 -q jumphostuser@jumphost IP",
        "debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect",
        "debug1: identity file /var/lib/awx/projects/POC_SDWAN/PRIVATEKEY/id_rsa type 0",
        "debug1: identity file /var/lib/awx/projects/POC_SDWAN/PRIVATEKEY/id_rsa-cert type -1",
        "debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0",
        "debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13",
        "debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002",
        "debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug1: Authenticating to TargetRouter_IP:22 as 'TargetRouteruser'",
        "debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \\"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\\"",
        "debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:42",
        "debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from TargetRouter_IP",
        "debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519",
        "debug3: send packet: type 20",
        "debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 20",
        "debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received",
        "debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal",
        "debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c",
        "debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa",
        "debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc",
        "debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc",
        "debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512",
        "debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512",
        "debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none",
        "debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none",
        "debug2: languages ctos: ",
        "debug2: languages stoc: ",
        "debug2: first_kex_follows 0 ",
        "debug2: reserved 0 ",
        "debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal",
        "debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256",
        "debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519",
        "debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr",
        "debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr",
        "debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256",
        "debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256",
        "debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com",
        "debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com",
        "debug2: languages ctos: ",
        "debug2: languages stoc: ",
        "debug2: first_kex_follows 0 ",
        "debug2: reserved 0 ",
        "debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org",
        "debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519",
        "debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com",
        "debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com",
        "debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32",
        "debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32",
        "debug3: send packet: type 30",
        "debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 31",
        "debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:zm0J3pMtudMGN3OeWviS22KkaZ+eQdEaiQeVfMVfLSk",
        "debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \\"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\\"",
        "debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:42",
        "debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from TargetRouter_IP",
        "debug1: Host 'TargetRouter_IP' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.",
        "debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:42",
        "debug3: send packet: type 21",
        "debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1",
        "debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks",
        "debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent",
        "debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 21",
        "debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received",
        "debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0",
        "debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks",
        "debug1: Will attempt key: /var/lib/awx/projects/POC_SDWAN/PRIVATEKEY/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZkS2TLBtCnTNT0GNwdbgHMJDU4ilaFSR/1vDGD3EPcQ explicit",
        "debug2: pubkey_prepare: done",
        "debug3: send packet: type 5",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 6",
        "debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth",
        "debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received",
        "debug3: send packet: type 50",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 53",
        "debug3: input_userauth_banner",
        "*---------------------------------------------------------------------*",
        "*  Company assets, including this system, should be used only for        *",
        "*      Company communications management approved purposes.              *",
        "*                                                                     *",
        "*  You should be aware that it may be a criminal offence to secure    *",
        "*    unauthorised access to any program or data in the system or      *",
        "*      to make any unauthorised modification to its contents.         *",
        "*                                                                     *",
        "*  If you are not authorised by Company management to access this        *",
        "*                     system, please LOGOFF now.                      *",
        "*                                                                     *",
        "* Company internal systems business authorised management audit any time *",
        "*---------------------------------------------------------------------*",
        "",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 51",
        "debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password",
        "debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password",
        "debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password",
        "debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey",
        "debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password",
        "debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey",
        "debug1: Next authentication method: publickey",
        "debug1: Offering public key: /var/lib/awx/projects/POC_SDWAN/PRIVATEKEY/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZkS2TLBtCnTNT0GNwdbgHMJDU4ilaFSR/1vDGD3EPcQ explicit",
        "debug3: send packet: type 50",
        "debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 51",
        "debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password",
        "debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method",
        "debug3: authmethod_lookup password",
        "debug3: remaining preferred: ,password",
        "debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password",
        "debug1: Next authentication method: password",
        "debug3: send packet: type 50",
        "debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 52",
        "debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.",
        "debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).",
        "Authenticated to TargetRouter_IP (via proxy).",
        "debug1: setting up multiplex master socket",
        "debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /tmp/bwrap_959_knd39plq/awx_959_a5darf8j/cp/e2d81b8595.otQRl5jTP8n15wvr",
        "debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug3: fd 3 is O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug3: fd 3 is O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug1: channel 0: new [/tmp/bwrap_959_knd39plq/awx_959_a5darf8j/cp/e2d81b8595]",
        "debug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 3",
        "debug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process",
        "debug2: control_persist_detach: background process is 2680",
        "debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug1: forking to background",
        "debug1: Entering interactive session.",
        "debug1: pledge: id",
        "debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds",
        "debug1: multiplexing control connection",
        "debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]",
        "debug3: channel_post_mux_listener: new mux channel 1 fd 6",
        "debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1: hello sent",
        "debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: cancel scheduled exit",
        "debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x00000001 len 4",
        "debug2: mux_master_process_hello: channel 1 slave version 4",
        "debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4",
        "debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote",
        "debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering",
        "debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering",
        "debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000004 len 4",
        "debug2: mux_master_process_alive_check: channel 1: alive check",
        "debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 2682",
        "debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent",
        "debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000002 len 104",
        "debug2: mux_master_process_new_session: channel 1: request tty 1, X 0, agent 0, subsys 0, term \\"\\", cmd \\"show system uptime\\", env 3",
        "debug3: mux_master_process_new_session: got fds stdin 7, stdout 8, stderr 9",
        "debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK",
        "debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]",
        "debug2: mux_master_process_new_session: channel_new: 2 linked to control channel 1",
        "debug2: channel 2: send open",
        "debug3: send packet: type 90",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 91",
        "debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback start",
        "debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2",
        "debug2: channel 2: request pty-req confirm 1",
        "debug3: send packet: type 98",
        "debug1: Sending environment.",
        "debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8",
        "debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0",
        "debug3: send packet: type 98",
        "debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8",
        "debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0",
        "debug3: send packet: type 98",
        "debug1: Sending env LANGUAGE = en_US:en",
        "debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0",
        "debug3: send packet: type 98",
        "debug1: Sending command: shell",
        "debug2: channel 2: request exec confirm 1",
        "debug3: send packet: type 98",
        "debug3: mux_session_confirm: sending success reply",
        "debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback done",
        "debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 99",
        "debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2",
        "debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 2",
        "debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 99",
        "debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2",
        "debug2: exec request accepted on channel 2",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 98",
        "debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0",
        "debug3: mux_exit_message: channel 2: exit message, exitval 2",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 98",
        "debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0",
        "debug2: channel 2: rcvd eow",
        "debug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 7 efd 9 [write])",
        "debug2: channel 2: input open -> closed",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 96",
        "debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof",
        "debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain",
        "debug3: receive packet: type 97",
        "debug2: channel 2: rcvd close",
        "debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close",
        "debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close",
        "debug2: channel 2: obuf empty",
        "debug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 8 efd 9 [write])",
        "debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed",
        "debug2: channel 2: send close",
        "debug3: send packet: type 97",
        "debug2: channel 2: is dead",
        "debug2: channel 2: gc: notify user",
        "debug3: mux_master_session_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 2",
        "debug2: channel 1: rcvd close",
        "debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain",
        "debug2: channel 1: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock 6 wfd 6 efd -1 [closed])",
        "debug2: channel 1: input open -> closed",
        "debug2: channel 2: gc: user detached",
        "debug2: channel 2: is dead",
        "debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting",
        "debug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3",
        "debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:",
        "  #1 mux-control (t16 nr0 i3/0 o1/0 e[closed]/0 fd 6/6/-1 sock 6 cc -1)",
        "  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/9 sock -1 cc -1)",
        "",
        "debug2: channel 1: obuf empty",
        "debug2: channel 1: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock 6 wfd 6 efd -1 [closed])",
        "debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe",
        "debug2: Received exit status from master 2",
        "Shared connection to TargetRouter_IP closed.",
        "debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed",
        "debug2: channel 1: is dead (local)",
        "debug2: channel 1: gc: notify user",
        "debug3: mux_master_control_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 1",
        "debug2: channel 1: gc: user detached",
        "debug2: channel 1: is dead (local)",
        "debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting",
        "debug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2",
        "debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:",
        "  #1 mux-control (t16 nr0 i3/0 o3/0 e[closed]/0 fd 6/6/-1 sock 6 cc -1)",
        "",
        "debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds"
    ],
    "stdout": "Invalid operation\\r\\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Invalid operation"
    ]
}

================================
```

Not able to understand why this error "Invalid Operation" with RC 2.
Please support and share suggestions